# Detecting Circles without using Hough Circles

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I have an image of a circle, I want to find the circle but not using hough circles.

I found a way, linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675203/calculating-centre-of-rotation-given-point-coordinates-at-different-positions/1414344#1414344).

But I can't find the transition coordinates from white to black as I don't know the x and y coordinates in the circle.  What other methods are there, or how can I make that approach work?

This is my test image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to first [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) the image to get rid of some of the noise around the circle. Then you can extract the edge of the circle using [`Canny`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de&gsc.tab=0) edge detection. Finally, [`findNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) to get a list of pixel coordinates.

---

I first did a quick prototype with Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('circle.png', 0)
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 20, 100)
points = np.array([p[0] for p in cv2.findNonZero(edges)])
```

---

And then ported it to C++, adding some extra code to save all the intermediate images and plot the found pixels.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img(cv::imread("circle.png", 0));

    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::threshold(img, mask, 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::imwrite("circle_1.png", mask);

    cv::Mat edges;
    cv::Canny(mask, edges, 20, 100);

    cv::imwrite("circle_2.png", edges);

    std::vector<cv::Point2i> points;
    cv::findNonZero(edges, points);

    cv::Mat output(cv::Mat::zeros(edges.size(), CV_8UC3));
    for (auto const& p : points) {
        output.at<cv::Vec3b>(p) = cv::Vec3b(127, 255, 127);
    }
    cv::imwrite("circle_3.png", output);
}
```

---

Output of `threshold`:

[image]

Output of `Canny`:

[image]

Re-plotted pixels:

[image]

Comment: If you need the circle parameters, you can use `minEnclosingCircle`

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (that is useful for more than just circles) would be to find the [image contours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) and do [image moment analysis](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments) on the circle to find it's centre of mass:

[image]

[image]

I recommend learning them if you'e going to move forward with image processing. They're pretty helpful approaches that transform images into more useful structures.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lamar Latrell

Comment: Lamar! Your knowledge is outstanding! Can you please msg me at : muliastudios@gmail.com ? I'm a computer science student and i'd could really use a quick help! Thank you so much!

Comment: @RoiMulia, I suggest you use StackOverflow for a faster response :)