# How to Find Diameter of the circle

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I have an image of a circle but my circle is not perfect 
Firstly I found transition coordinates
[Detecting Circles without using Hough Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400390/detecting-circles-without-using-hough-circles)
and than ı use this formula https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675203/calculating-centre-of-rotation-given-point-coordinates-at-different-positions/1414344#1414344
Finally ı have fourn radiuses which the longest and shortest
Now I have this image:
[image]

BUt they are radius I need to find diameter How to find diameter from image??
Or How to I can find mutual/symetric/ point in a circle

Comment: Maybe diameter = 2*radius ?

Comment: you are right but my circles are not perfect so 2*r is not comletely true

Comment: what do you mean with "not perfect" ? The diameter from 2*r is as accurate as the radius is.

Comment: distances from center is not equivalent for every point

Comment: and in the same way, the diameter will not be the same for each point, so I dont understand whats is wrong with using the radius. Otherwise you need a quite different algorithm, but taking the diameter instead of radius alone does not solve anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways to do this:

1. I think you need to measure it from image: 
   so use edge detection (blue line width from left to right = **width of bounding box of the blue pixels**) then count pixels.
   If you need then convert to any unit you want like inch (using pixel per inch).
   If your circle is not perfect circle (stretched) measure in many direction so you can find its deviation too.
2. There is another way named **Monte-Carlo method**: 
   first generate random `x` and `y` (inside square) and then evaluate that point `(x, y)` is inside the circle or not and count the number of inside occurrences, then you can calculate the Area of circle using ratio on inside `count/total` (and therefore diameter).
3. without using random numbers:
   fill(color) circle inside then simply count black pixels this is = to Area outside circle => Total Area(Square Area)- black pixel Area = **Circle Area** => calculate diameter.

Comment: Yes I need to measure it from image Thank you I will try it

Comment: using monte carlo to get the area of a circle is a nice example to introduce monte carlo to students, but in practice this is rarely a good application of mc. It is rather easy to think of simpler ways that converge faster and are more accurate. Monte carlo makes sense when your data is high dimensional and any other method would be too complicated, which is both not the case here.

Comment: using this method is easy here it just need counting pixels of image inside over total pixels to get the Area of circle. (so you may not run random numbers). i mentioned here to get the idea of calculating Area, by the way it is a valid method.

Comment: I didnt say that it is not a valid method. You just stated a much better way than using mc by counting the pixels. If you would do the same with mc, which uses random numbers by definition, it would take some time to converge and the result would be less accurate.

Answer (score 2):

For this image, the approaches mentioned are overkill. Just find the bounding box of the non-black pixels. Because of sampling artifacts, the horizontal and vertical side lengths may differ by one or two pixels.

If I am right, the outer circle is 277 x 273 pixels. If you consider the difference to be significant, then this is an ellipse, not a circle.

Comment: bounding box of the non-black pixels. this is what i said in (1).